# Reading two line continuously using getline function in c++

Tags: c++, getline

I was learning how to read strings with getline function.

I know that getline function read string as far as we don't hit enter or the size value in the getline parameter go cross. As far as I tried getline function to read one line of string I had not faced any problem.

But when I was trying to read two line of string one after another in two different char array i got the output that was not expected to me.
To understand my question follow bellow lines

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char line1[10];
    char line2[10];
    cin.getline(line1,7);
    cin.getline(line2,7);
    cout << "\nline1 =" << line1 <<endl;
    cout << "line2 =" << line2 <<endl;
}
```

When I ran the above program it ask me for input then I gave orange as first input and hit the enter button.

Next it ask me to give the second input .then i gave banana and hit the enter button .in this case it produce the result i expected .But if enter oranges for the first input it does not wait for me to enter the second input.

As a result line1 store orange but line2 remains blank.
Now my question is that there is no wrong with line1 storing orange. But I don't understand why the line2 remains blank should not it contain the data that remains after line1 take input I mean should not line2 contain s as value.

Because orange is a 6 digit word so getline will stores the first six digit after then a null character will be added as I set the size of geline 7.

Then other remaing data will be assigend in the next call of getline function.So should not s stored in line2 as after s a new_line character is read for the first time.

Why will be line2 remain blank and why the screen doesn't stop for taking input after giving the first input?

Comment: Can you please clean up the large paragraph that constitutes the bulk of your question so that we can read it?

Comment: okk.i am trying to make it short. But i thought it was good to give full description of my problem

Comment: Do you understand what the second parameter to `cin.getline` does?  (Nudge: Try entering `marmalade` for line 1.)

Comment: The syntax of `getline` is a little weird. What are you trying to do with the second argument `7`?

Comment: Much like code, readability will benefit from structure and whitespace.  In any case, what do you expect to happen when you specify a maximum of 7 characters to read?  When you read `oranges`, that is 7, and so the return character is not read.  It will be picked up by the next `getline` which will only read the return and think it's an empty string.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated i am trying to store first six digit of character in the line1 char array  in case the user give more than 6 digit character

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i tried marmalade . there line1 contains marmal and line2 remain blank as my problem was

Comment: @paddy it makes sense your comment.but should not line2 contain abcd if i would give the first argument as orangesabcd .But it still give line1 =orange line2 =          it could be happen i could not understand your logic .But can you show me how will store two string in two line variable

Comment: I believe the answer written by user4581301 describes why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::istream::getline` is being overloaded with data.

[According to cppreference,](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

> Behaves as [UnformattedInputFunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction). After constructing and checking the sentry object, extracts characters from *this and stores them in successive locations of the array whose first element is pointed to by s, until any of the following occurs (tested in the order shown):
>
> - end of file condition occurs in the input sequence (in which case `setstate(eofbit)` is executed)
> - the next available character c is the delimiter, as determined by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`. The delimiter is extracted (unlike [basic_istream::get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)) and counted towards gcount(), but is not stored.
> - **`count-1` characters have been extracted (in which case `setstate(failbit)` is executed).**

Emphasis mine.

```
cin.getline(line1,7);
//                ^ This is count
```

can read only 6 characters with the 7th reserved for the null terminator. "oranges" is seven characters, and this places `cin` in a non-readable error state that must be cleared before reading can be continued. Reading of the second line

```
cin.getline(line2,7);
```

instantly fails and no data is read.

The obvious solution is

```
cin.getline(line1, sizeof(line1));
```

to take advantage of the whole array. But...

Any IO transaction should be tested for success, so

```
if (cin.getline(line1, sizeof(line1)))
{
    // continue gathering 
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

is a better option.

Better still would be to use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to almost eliminate the size constraints.