# What happens when getline does not read until new line?

Tags: c++, getline

I have seen quite a number of related posts, but did not get an answer to the following question.

Consider:

```
char buffer[4];
cin.getline(buffer, 4);
cout << buffer << endl;
cin.getline(buffer, 4);
cout << buffer << endl;
```

If I enter `abc` on input, I am given a chance to enter the second line and both lines appear correctly in the output. However, if I enter `abcd`or, for that matter, anything longer than three characters, I do not get to enter the second line and the second line of output is empty. What exactly is going on?

Comment: I assume it has to do with the `\n`

Comment: Possible duplicate (maybe there are better dupes out there, not voting): [Reading two line continuously using getline function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57087499/reading-two-line-continuously-using-getline-function-in-c)

Comment: @TonyTannous That's what the title of the question says. I am trying to understand what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see that [`std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

> extracts characters [...] until any of the
>   following occurs (tested in the order shown):
>
> - end of file condition occurs in the input sequence (in which case `setstate(eofbit)` is executed)
> - the next available character `c` is the delimiter, as determined by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`. The delimiter is extracted (unlike
>     `basic_istream::get()`) and counted towards `gcount()`, but is not stored.
> - `count-1` characters have been extracted (in which case `setstate(failbit)` is executed).
>
> If the function extracts no characters (e.g. if `count < 1`),
>   `setstate(failbit)` is executed.
>
> In any case, if `count>0`, it then stores a null character `CharT()` into
>   the next successive location of the array and updates `gcount()`.

In our case, because we've entered too many characters for the storage, we hit the third condition, and the fail bit is set on the stream.

The fail bit can be unset using `std::cin.clear()`.

Comment: Putting `cin.clear()` resolved the problem, so that the second `getline` continues to read the line that was not completely read by the first one.